# Using an Excel Macro to find duplicates across multiple workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm pretty new to macros, literally just started learning them.
Basically, I have a dilemma. I have a workbook with 4 sheets that each have about 800k rows or more, this is a list of address and numbers i want to remove from my other lists. Is there a way for me to create a macro (in that workbook) that will search for all those address/numbers across other workbooks that will be in the same folder?

basically, I'd like the macro to either delete the rows that have that information, or i'd like it to highlight them so i can go and delete them.

Is that possible..?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Full answer would be probably very long. To give you some hints:

To loop through all files in a given folder:

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim MyFolder as String, MyFile as String, wbk as Workbook
MyFile = Dir(MyFolder) 'DIR gets the first file of the folder

'Loop through all files in a folder until DIR cannot find anymore
Do While MyFile <> “”

    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & MyFile)

    ' Some code
    ' Some code
    ' Some code

    wbk.Close savechanges:=True
    MyFile = Dir 'DIR gets the next file in the folder

Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

To check if some cell has a value that can be found in some range in another workbook, you can use: `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`.

To delete a row: `ws.Rows(row_number).Delete` where ws is a worksheet.

If you are just starting it might take you some time before you make it work. Maybe next time try to be more specific with your question.

Comment: That is actually super helpful :)

Comment: Also, as for my question...I'm not too sure of how to put it other than that, I just need to figure out how to make a macro that will look for a specific set of addresses/numbers (I want those lists to be in the same workbook as the macro)  in other workbooks and delete them completely.  Do you know of anything specific I could check out to help me eventually make this?

Comment: The question is too broad and when you state it like that it looks as if you wanted someone to post a full working macro. Instead people are more likely to answer when the question is more specific. For example: "How do I delete a row in Excel using vba?". Most of the questions like that are already answered on Stack Overflow or elsewhere. You literally just google "vba row delete" and click the first link. Also it's good to write about something you tried but didn't work. Chances are that it's easier to fix it that to write new code. So just try it and use google a lot. Good luck ;)